# Function for search days in month

Tags: sql, tableau-api, mdx

I have a project in tableau and i want count days in month marked in the filter "Fiscal time hierarchy". 
For example i mark on filter 2019.07 and my results is 31 and when also mark 2019.06 (+2019.07) i want results 61.

My tableau is connect to server so i can't change dimension to measures. I have to have a MDX query - in tableau "Calculated Members"

For today i prepared some code, but i have error when i mark on filter more that one time. Is working for one month or one year, but not working for two month, two year.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs4aX.jpg

My mdx:

```
   count( descendants([Time].[Fiscal Time Hierarchy].CurrentMember, 3))
```

Results for filtering 2019.07 -> 31 is correct
Results for filtering 2019.07 + 2019.06 ->

ERROR

Error text for two times:
An error occurred while communicating with data source 'Model (Ariadne)'.

> Error Code: A7AED4D2
>   Database error 0x80004005:
>   ?The MDX CURRENTMEMBER function failed to execute because the coordinate for the 'Fiscal Year' attribute contains a set.

```
Technical details:

    RootActivityId: 251a2e39-6466-46d3-bec0-c5e305c186eb
    Data (UTC): 8/1/2019 7:10:12 AM
      ; The query: WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[daycount] AS
      'count( descendants([Time].[Fiscal Time Hierarchy], 3))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 0, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_556757519052849152] AS
      '([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] - [Measures].[Revenue BDG 2020 before ADJ (LC)])',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_995295533060087809] AS
      'IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_591378942957641731] AS
      '[Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)]',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_591378942953566209] AS
      '(1 - ([Measures].[Revenue BDG 2020 before ADJ (LC)] / (([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] * IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))))) / IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW()))))))))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_322851815536898052] AS
      '(1 - ([Measures].[Revenue FC1 2020 before ADJ (LC)] / (([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] * IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))))) / IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW()))))))))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_322851815528308738] AS
      '(1 - ([Measures].[Revenue FC1 2020 before ADJ (LC)] / [Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)]))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_322851815536275459] AS
      '((([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] * IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))))) / IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))))) - [Measures].[Revenue FC1 2020 before ADJ (LC)])',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_995295533059760128] AS
      'IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_591378943005073413] AS
      '((([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] * IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))))) / IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))))) - [Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)])',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_995295533060726786] AS
      '(([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] * IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))))) / IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW()))))))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_995295533073104899] AS
      'DateValue(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW()))))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_322851815528140801] AS
      '([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] - [Measures].[Revenue FC1 2020 before ADJ (LC)])',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_591378942953381888] AS
      '((([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] * IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))))) / IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))))) - [Measures].[Revenue BDG 2020 before ADJ (LC)])',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_591378942958161924] AS
      '[Measures].[Revenue BDG 2020 before ADJ (LC)]',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_556757519053275138] AS
      '(1 - ([Measures].[Revenue BDG 2020 before ADJ (LC)] / [Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)]))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_322851815527907328] AS
      '[Measures].[Revenue FC1 2020 before ADJ (LC)]',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    SELECT
    {[Measures].[daycount]} DIMENSION PROPERTIES [MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME],[MEMBER_CAPTION] ON COLUMNS
    FROM [Model]
    WHERE
    StripCalculatedMembers(CROSSJOIN(
      Intersect(
        {[Platform - Attributes].[Declared Seller Type].&[B2C]:[Platform - Attributes].[Declared Seller Type].&[C2C]},
        AddCalculatedMembers( Except(
          [Platform - Attributes].[Declared Seller Type].Members,
          {[Platform - Attributes].[Declared Seller Type].Levels(0).Members}) )),
      CROSSJOIN(
        {[Site].[Country Hierarchy].[Country].&[Poland]},
        {[Time].[Fiscal Time Hierarchy].[Fiscal Month].&[2019-06]:[Time].[Fiscal Time Hierarchy].[Fiscal Month].&[2019-07]})))
    WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[daycount] AS
      'count( descendants([Time].[Fiscal Time Hierarchy], 3))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 0, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_556757519052849152] AS
      '([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] - [Measures].[Revenue BDG 2020 before ADJ (LC)])',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_995295533060087809] AS
      'IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_591378942957641731] AS
      '[Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)]',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_591378942953566209] AS
      '(1 - ([Measures].[Revenue BDG 2020 before ADJ (LC)] / (([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] * IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))))) / IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW()))))))))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_322851815536898052] AS
      '(1 - ([Measures].[Revenue FC1 2020 before ADJ (LC)] / (([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] * IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))))) / IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW()))))))))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_322851815528308738] AS
      '(1 - ([Measures].[Revenue FC1 2020 before ADJ (LC)] / [Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)]))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_322851815536275459] AS
      '((([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] * IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))))) / IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))))) - [Measures].[Revenue FC1 2020 before ADJ (LC)])',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_995295533059760128] AS
      'IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_591378943005073413] AS
      '((([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] * IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))))) / IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))))) - [Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)])',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_995295533060726786] AS
      '(([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] * IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))))) / IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW()))))))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_995295533073104899] AS
      'DateValue(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW()))))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_322851815528140801] AS
      '([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] - [Measures].[Revenue FC1 2020 before ADJ (LC)])',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_591378942953381888] AS
      '((([Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)] * IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m", CDate(34700), IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("m",1,INT(NOW())))), CDate(34700)))))))) / IIF(IsEmpty(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))),NULL,DAY(IIF(IsEmpty(INT(NOW())),NULL,DATEADD("d",-1,INT(NOW())))))) - [Measures].[Revenue BDG 2020 before ADJ (LC)])',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_591378942958161924] AS
      '[Measures].[Revenue BDG 2020 before ADJ (LC)]',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_556757519053275138] AS
      '(1 - ([Measures].[Revenue BDG 2020 before ADJ (LC)] / [Measures].[Trans Revenue Nett (LC)]))',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    MEMBER [Measures].[Calculation_322851815527907328] AS
      '[Measures].[Revenue FC1 2020 before ADJ (LC)]',
      SOLVE_ORDER = 65535, SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE
    SELECT
    {[Measures].[daycount]} DIMENSION PROPERTIES [MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME],[MEMBER_CAPTION] ON COLUMNS
    FROM [Model]
    WHERE
    StripCalculatedMembers(CROSSJOIN(
      Intersect(
        {[Platform - Attributes].[Declared Seller Type].&[B2C]:[Platform - Attributes].[Declared Seller Type].&[C2C]},
        AddCalculatedMembers( Except(
          [Platform - Attributes].[Declared Seller Type].Members,
          {[Platform - Attributes].[Declared Seller Type].Levels(0).Members}) )),
      CROSSJOIN(
        {[Site].[Country Hierarchy].[Country].&[Poland]},
        {[Time].[Fiscal Time Hierarchy].[Fiscal Month].&[2019-06]:[Time].[Fiscal Time Hierarchy].[Fiscal Month].&[2019-07]})))
```